# One word to describe increase in number of items?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

I am looking for a single verb to describe when the size of a list is increased by adding more items to it. Like:

> The list ... as more items was added to it.

My first thought was that there should exist a simple, single word for it. Words like *expanded* or *got bigger* didn't seem correct.

(This question actually came to my mind while coding. I wanted to name a function that added items to a list and thus make it bigger. I couldn't thought of a single verb for it.)

Comment: This question may be migrated to [ell.se]

Comment: @Kris, as I was posting the question, it came to my mind, too. If a moderator thinks it's better suited for that site, migrating it would be fine.

Comment: Isn't *[embiggened](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/embiggened)* the usual word for that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The list grew as more items were added to it.

Comment: Oh yes... That's the word. Why hadn't I thought of that! Thanks.

Comment: I've seen tchrist get far fewer votes for 10 000% more prestigious answers.